# How to solve a differential equation for a vector field?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-fields, boundary-value-problem

A point source in a isotropic homogeneous sphere,
continuously produces particles (like charges) and generates currents flowing in the sphere.

A point sink conversely absorbs particles.

When the source and the sink produces and absorbs particles at the same rate, a steady current field is then formed.

In the genral case, an equal amount of sources and sinks are distributed in the sphere, and form a steady current field $\vec J(\vec r)$.

From conservation of flow we know
$$
\nabla\cdot\vec J(\vec r)=-\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}
=F(\vec r),\quad 0\leq r\leq R,
$$
where $\vec J(\vec r)$ is the vector field to be solved, $F(\vec r)$ a given scalar field, $R$ the sphere's radius.
Because particles cannot run out of the sphere, the current must turn back before approaching the spherical surface.
Therefore the boundary condition reads,
$$
\left.{\vec J}\cdot{\vec n}\right|_{r=R}=0,
$$
where $\vec n$ is the normal vector of the surface.

Is this problem well-defined? How to solve it?

---

A point source can be mathematically described as $I\delta(\vec r)$ since
$$
\int\mathrm d^3\vec rI\delta(\vec r)=I=\int \mathrm d\vec S\cdot\vec J(\vec r)=\int\mathrm d^3\vec r\nabla\cdot\vec J(\vec r).
$$
And a dipole (a point source and a point sink of the same current, infinitesimally close to each other) can be described as
$$
I\delta(\vec r+\vec d/2)-I\delta(\vec r-\vec d/2)=I\vec d\cdot\nabla\delta(\vec r)=\vec p\cdot\nabla\delta(\vec r),
$$
where $\vec d$ is the vector from the source to the sink, and $I\to\infty,\vec d\to0$ while $\vec p=I\vec d$ remains a finite constant value, called a dipole.

The field $F(\vec r)$ can be seen as a summation of distributed dipoles.
For brevity, let $F(\vec r)=\vec p\cdot\nabla\delta(\vec r)$, so
$$
\nabla\cdot\vec J(\vec r)=\vec p\cdot\nabla\delta(\vec r),\quad
0\leq r\leq R,\\
\left.\vec J(\vec r)\cdot\vec n\right|_{r=R}=0.
$$

---

I tried Fourier transformatin and get
$$
\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\vec k\cdot\vec R}\vec J(\vec R)+\mathrm i\vec k
\cdot\vec j(\vec k)=\mathrm i\vec k\cdot\vec p,
$$
where $\vec j(\vec k)$ is the transformed form. I can't go any further.

I thought I should find the vector eigenfunction $\vec u$ of the operator $\nabla$, which means
$$
\nabla\cdot\vec u(\vec r)=\vec k\cdot\vec u(\vec r),
$$
where $\vec k$ is a constant vector, the eigenvalue.
I need three vector eigenfunctions for a complete basis.

Comment: Hello, welcome to math.stackexchange. Please add some context on where you encountered this problem, what tools are at your disposal, what methods you have tried or what special cases you have been able to solve. If not, it will likely be regarded as a low quality question (as it frankly looks like someone could have copy-pasted from a homework set) and closed, benefitting no one. For instance, if $f$ is the constant scalar field with value $1$, can you solve this equation?

Comment: @Arkady Thank you, and I updated my text.